# Monks in a temple

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual

Try somehow make sense of the image below. All the necessary information to solve this puzzle is there.

Good luck!

[image]

Edit: The puzzle consists of two parts. First, focus on the blue parts(what's inside the 6 rounded blue rectangles/squares). It's only **after** you've figured out the blue parts you'll(hopefully) understand the number part.

Comment: Does the font in the numbers matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: "after you've figured out the blue parts you'll(hopefully) understand the number part" …nope.

Comment: @Jan Ivan :) Have you fully completed the blue parts?

Comment: @Prim3numbah fully, means something more than just sentence… I guess I should answer that question somehow with numbers… but I have no idea how

Comment: @Jan Ivan Yes. If you've made it that far, then rot13(qba'g gerng gur qvtvgf nf ahzore**f**). Here's where the 'knowledge' - tag plays a part

Comment: @Jan Ivan, you can post a partial answer if you like, since it seems noone else figured out the blue parts. I will add a hint regarding the number part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial answer**
First (by trial and error):

> Find what belongs to what -> 1C, 2A and 3B

Second:

> 1 means shifting each letter by 13 (or rot13) and read 5 letters on diagonal -> WHATI
>  2 means starting from middle and read 9 letters -> STHETITLE
>  3 means 1st row 2nd column (O)+ 1st row 1st column (F) + … and so on -> OFTHISBOOK

Together:

> WHAT IS THE TITLE OF THIS BOOK

And numbers:

> I have no idea what to do with 5567961971879, I also don't read books in English. When reversed it kind of looks like "black big bless." Maybe it has something to do with "Monks in a temple."

Comment: This is ofc so far correct. As for the numbers(remember the 'knowledge'-tag), rot13((ybbx bayvar ;))

Comment: btw, previously when I said: rot13("qba'g gerng gurz nf ahzore**f**"", V bayl zrnag, gerng vg nf **bar** ynetr ahzore. Fb ab arrq gb pbaireg gb yrggref(whfg hfr Tbbtyr))

Comment: rot13(vagreangvbany fgnaqneq - - - - ahzore)

Answer (score 3):

I see that nearly two full days has passed with no updates to the first answer, so I will complete the puzzle. @janIvan solved the hardest part of the puzzle, though, so should be given the checkmark.

The solution:

> @janIvan found that the first part of the puzzle generates the phrase "What is the title of this book?"
>  For the second part of the puzzle, the number 5567961971879 is a book ISBN number written ***backwards***. The book is [Cryptica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1791697658), by Paul Laane. The subject matter of the book relates to the title of the puzzle: ten monks are brought, blindfolded, to a sacred hidden temple, called Cryptica.
> So the answer to the puzzle is: **Cryptica**.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer :) The tick will go to Jan as he solved the hardest part, like you say. But I'm glad you finished it!